# R -- Order List Names by Number

Tags: r, list, sorting

I have assembled a nested list with 100 parent lists, each of which contains multiple (n=34) character strings. My goal is to write each of these 100 parents lists into a different text file. I have been able to successfully output the text files (code is included below); however, the order is incorrect.

When I list the elements contained within the parent list I get the following:

```
ls(ctl_out)
   [1] "ctl001" "ctl002" "ctl003" "ctl004" "ctl005"
  ...
  [96] "ctl096" "ctl097" "ctl098" "ctl099" "ctl100"
```

The order listed above is correct (beginning at 001 and ending at 100).  However, when I ask R to order the list and print the first element I get the following:

```
ctl_out[order(ctl_out[1]))]
  $ctl067
```

Consequently, when I open the text file that is saved with the file name ctl001.txt it has all of the information that should be in #067 rather than #001.

Is anyone familiar with a method to re-order or sort the list order so that `ctl_out[order(ctl_out[1])]` yields `$ctl001` instead of `$ctl067`?

For reference, I am developing the parent `ctl_out` list using the following code (after cleaning out my environment so that it only includes the 100 parent lists):

```
ctl_out <- as.list.environment(environment())
```

I am then writing out each of the 100 parent lists into individual text files using the following code:

```
for(i in seq_along(ctl_out)) {
   write.table(ctl_out[i], paste0('ctl', sprintf('%03d', i), '.txt'),
               row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE, sep = '\t', quote = FALSE)
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is `clt_out[order(names(clt_out))]` what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to mark this question as answered, I would like to credit @wush978 for his clear answer in the previous comment.

To fix this error, after constructing the `ctl_out` list using:

```
ctl_out <- as.list.environment(environment())
```

You then apply the order function as follows:

```
ctl_out <- ctl_out[order(names(ctl_out))]
```

The resulting ordered list (`ctl_out`) can then be exported so that each list (001-100) is saved as an individually numbered text file:

```
for(i in seq_along(ctl_out)) {
   write.table(ctl_out[i], paste0('ctl', sprintf('%03d', i), '.txt'),
   row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE, sep = '\t', quote = FALSE)
}
```

Thanks again.